Have there been any Republican legislative proposals that all people with an Y chromosome should be declared male?
With the 'political football' over Imane Khelif taking a large chunk of Fox News and similar outlets (tying in to their rage against the transgender, of course) and seemingly channeling the declarations of Republican leaders, e.g.

N.B. Trump also said something about it.

“I’d like to congratulate the young woman who transitioned from a man to a boxer,” Trump said. “You saw, he won, she won the gold medal,” he added ironically.

Also

right-wing organizations in the United States, including the Independent Women’s Forum and CPAC, via its chair Matt Schlapp, have paid for sponsored posts on Musk’s X platform, calling her “a man“—posts that appear when users search for information on the controversy.

(I initially didn't have anywhere as much detail/quotes, but I got a lot of comments that we shouldn't confuse Trump or Vance with some fiction  author, Fox News doesn't matter, etc.)
Have there been any Republican legislative proposals that all people with with an Y chromosome should be declared males? (I'm not talking about any genitalia, because that would not matter in such a case. So strictly whether the are any genetics-based legislative proposals from the GOP.)

The question's context and associated polemics against Fox News seem unrelated to the actual question, which is otherwise answerable.

Why the restriction to Republican proposals?

@Jen: because the Q may be too broad otherwise. If you feel you should ask if [US] Democrats or Italian 'Melonists' also proposed it, feel free to ask your own Q.

@Jen: Also, feel free to ask if any prominent Democrats suggested Khelif is really a man.

It would not be too broad to simply ask if there are such legislative proposals in the US, no matter the party source. I already feel free to ask any on-topic question I would like to ask; I do not need your reminder about that.

@Jen: thanks for your suggestion, but I feel it's much less relevant in this context. (See comment right above your last why I think that, right now.)

VTD.  Can't help thinking this is a way to tie the Republicans to a totally unrelated controversy in Olympic boxing.  If the justification for asking is derived from JD Vance's tweet, then please limit the Q's scope to JD Vance specifically.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica huh? The Vance tweet is about that boxing thing too (see what he's quoting). I can't see what I could possibly ask about those communications as such. They seem totally clear to me. I'm asking if there have been any legislative initiatives reflecting that rhetoric.

I'm curious if such a definition can conceivably work. Are you aware of any examples where such a definition would fail?

Q: Have there been any Republican legislative proposals that all people with an Y chromosome should be declared male?
For Congress as of this writing, no. There are two bills dated May 5, 2023, — one regarding passports, the other TSA pre-check clearance — that limit sex designations to "male" or "female" based on sex characteristics (including sex chromosomes) "present at birth".

H.R.3101 - TPA Act
H.R.3102 - TSA Act

These bills appear to exclude females with Swyer syndrome.

Girls with Swyer syndrome have an XY chromosomal makeup (as boys normally do) instead of an XX chromosomal makeup (as girls normally do). Despite having the XY chromosomal makeup, girls with Swyer syndrome look female and have functional female genitalia and structures including a vagina, uterus and fallopian tubes.


Wyoming legislation, HOUSE BILL NO. HB0050, sponsored by Republican Representative Jeanette Ward, provides the following:

(ii)  "Female" means a person whose biological reproductive system is developed to produce ova and/or who exhibits XX chromosomes and does not exhibit a Y chromosome;
(iii)  "Male" means a person whose biological reproductive system is developed to fertilize the ova of a female and/or who exhibits XY chromosomes or exhibits a Y chromosome;

This suggests that females with Swyer syndrome should be classified as males.

What about state laws? I wasn't asking strictly about federal ones. AFAICT "In Tennesee, the language used to define sex is "a person's immutable biological sex as determined by anatomy and genetics existing at the time of birth."" Which is close enough, albeit includes genitalia as well. AFAICT from IOC's method of testing Khelif passed both those tests. Which of course doesn't exclude the 'conspiracy' [theory] that she wasn't tested 'properly'.

"And/or" means either of the two possibilities or both. According to the definition in the text of the bill, people with the Swyer syndrom are both female and male.

Not in those exact terms of chromosomes, but some recent (mostly Republican backed, AFAICT) state legislation, e.g. in Tennessee uses definitions like:

a person's immutable biological sex as determined by anatomy and genetics existing at the time of birth.

(A number of Republican legislators expressed their belief when passing those laws that there are only two sexes. Such expressions of "original intent" are sometimes taken into account by courts when the language of the law is somewhat ambiguous.)
An  older, 2019 paper only lists Mississippi (p. 236) as including 'genetics' in their definition,  but several states (South Dakota, Illinois, Indiana, Missouri, Kansas, Wisconsin) referring to "a person's chromosomes"



(The table was split over two pages, I've rearranged it a bit above.) They do list the exact house bills for each state, as you can see, but tracking down the proponents in each case is a bit of work. (The paper does note that these were mostly "bathroom bills" [i.e. defining sex for the purpose of bathroom access], and the bill selection is claimed to be 'random'.)
Tracking down one of those, e.g. Kansas SB 513 of 2016, its exact wording was

"Sex" means the physical condition of being male or female,
which is determined by a person's chromosomes, and is identified at birth
by a person's anatomy.

I'm not terribly familiar with how the Kansas legislature works, but the sponsor is listed as a Committee (on Ways and Means) rather than an individual (or individuals). But that bill died in the Committee on Education, FWTW. The Republican party had an overwhelming majority in the Kansas Senate at the time.

AP also notes in April 2024:

Republicans in more than a dozen states have proposed bills this year that would codify definitions of sex. [...]
The Alabama House of Representatives voted 77-24 for the legislation that declares “there are only two sexes” and writes definitions for male, female, boy, girl, mother and father into state law. The bill now moves to the Alabama Senate.

Alas, I have yet to find a round-up of these (like the 2019 one) that tries to categorize them. The AP piece discusses one bill from Alabama, which mentions ... 'genetic anomaly':

It says a woman is a person “who has, had, will have, or would have, but for a developmental anomaly, genetic anomaly, or accident, the reproductive system that at some point produces ova.”

This appears to be a somewhat standardized definition being proposed, as a quick search also finds it e.g. in a West Virginia bill/amendment (HB5243 HFA STEELE #1 which is probably from Republican delegate Brandon Steele.).
Interestingly the WV proposal (and perhaps even the Alabama one) is more explicit that:

Individuals with "differences in sex development" (also known as "DSD" or "intersex conditions") are not a third sex.

Similar wording regarding DSD (and 'genetic anomaly') appears in Minnesota Senate Bill SF 5466 ("Minnesota Women's Bill of Rights"), proposed by 5 Republicans (Lucero, Gruenhagen,  Drazkowski, Bahr & Green).
